# I can't seem to test for a null in this c# Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity App that is using c#.

I am getting a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the line:

```
WeatherDict.Add(WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId, new List<WeatherMaps>());
```

for `WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId`

I am trying to check for null by using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` as you can see.

```
for (int i = 0; i < WeatherTypes.Length; i++)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId))
    {
        if (!WeatherDict.ContainsKey(WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId))
        {
            WeatherDict.Add(WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId, new List<WeatherMaps>());
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
if (WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId != null || WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId != "")
```

But that still throws the same exception.

Is there another way to check for null?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if WheatherTypes is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Weathertypes` is null, the following code will cause a null reference exception:

```
if (WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId != null || WeatherTypes[i].WeatherId != "")
```

A safer approach looks like this.

```
if (WeatherTypes == null || WeatherTypes[i] == null)
```

You should learn to use the debugger. It will allow you to step through the code and look and see exactly what is null.

Comment: Thanks!  So I don't need this line: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` ? I have been trying to use Visual Studio and Unity together, but it's slow progress.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: My code checks for null. If you need to know if the string is empty, you will need to test for that. But an empty string won't cause a null reference exception.

Comment: Oh ok thanks!  So I could just use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` because that checks for both Null and Empty I am assuming.  Thanks! Again!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: Yes, as long as you first check if `WeatherTypes` is null.